# Stack Exchange Dark Mode

Tags: script, style

*This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)*

## [Stack Exchange Dark Mode](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#stack-exchange-dark-mode)

Dark theme for Stack Exchange, chat, and SEDE.

Some elements like sidebars and footers have reduced opacity until focused/mouseover. Some colours like badges and bounty indicators are retained.

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Also works for chat:**

[image]

**Now has support for SO, SU, and SF logos:**

[image]

### License

[MIT](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/LICENCE)

### Download

**[View source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/StackExchangeDarkMode.user.js) ([Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/StackExchangeDarkMode.user.js))**

Userscripts require [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) to be installed on your browser.

If you are on Android, your browser options are [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) *(recommended)* or [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

### Code

This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)

[Bug reports](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues), Forks, and PRs welcome!

Comment: If you are viewing this one year later, there has been many improvements and the screenshots are outdated. Try the script out for yourself!

Comment: :( perhaps I came to the wrong place.

Comment: Does this work on mobile?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-QwertyuiopASzdL: Exactly what I was wondering too. The thing is, StackExchange needs to be re-programmed to incorporate dark mode by default instead of depending on user mods run with TamperMonkey.

Comment: It does, for mobile browsers that support userscript managers.